# Keras: functional API what should the Input layer be for the embedding layer?

Tags: python, keras

I am using the Keras functional API to create a neural net that takes a word embedding layer as input for a sentence classification task. But my code breaks right at the beginning of connecting the input and the embedding layers. Following a tutorial at https://medium.com/tensorflow/predicting-the-price-of-wine-with-the-keras-functional-api-and-tensorflow-a95d1c2c1b03, I have code like below:

```
max_seq_length=100 #i.e., sentence has a max of 100 words 
word_weight_matrix = ... #this has a shape of 9825, 300, i.e., the vocabulary has 9825 words and each is a 300 dimension vector 
deep_inputs = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,))
embedding = Embedding(9825, 300, input_length=max_seq_length,
                          weights=word_weight_matrix, trainable=False)(deep_inputs) # line A
hidden = Dense(targets, activation="softmax")(embedding)
model = Model(inputs=deep_inputs, outputs=hidden)
```

Then line A causes an error that states below:

```
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "embedding_1" with a  weight list of length 9825, but the layer was expecting 1 weights. Provided weights: [[-0.04057981  0.05743935  0.0109863  ...,  0.0072...
```

And I don't really understand what the error means...

It seems that the Input layer isn't defined properly... Previously when I use the Sequential model with the embedding layer defined exactly the same, everything works OK. But when I switch to functional API, I have this error.

Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this updated code: you have to use `len(vocabulary) + 1` in Embedding layer! and `weights=[word_weight_matrix]`

```
max_seq_length=100 #i.e., sentence has a max of 100 words 
word_weight_matrix = ... #this has a shape of 9825, 300, i.e., the vocabulary has 9825 words and each is a 300 dimension vector 
deep_inputs = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,))
embedding = Embedding(9826, 300, input_length=max_seq_length,
                      weights=[word_weight_matrix], trainable=False)(deep_inputs) # line A
hidden = Dense(targets, activation="softmax")(embedding)
model = Model(inputs=deep_inputs, outputs=hidden)
```

Comment: Thank you, weights=[word_weight_matrix] is the fix. len(vocabulary) + 1 causes another problem though which is shape being incompatible. When it is len(vocabulary) that works.